# htaccess load parked domain name in subfolder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a parked domain that I want to load from a sub-folder.

In my root public_html folder I have the following in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:www\.)?parkeddomain\.com(?:|/)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_domains/myparkeddomain_com(?:|/)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /_domains/myparkeddomain_com/$1 [NC,L,NS,QSA]
```

The problem is when I go to my `parkeddomain.com` I see my index in `/_domains/myparkeddomain_com/` folder but when I try to install Wordpress there it redirects and gets into `parkeddomain.com/_domains/myparkeddomain_com/wp-admin/install.php`.

How can I configure so it loads without showing `/_domains/myparkeddomain_com/` ?

I want `/folder` and `/folder/folder/file.php` on my `parkeddomain.com` to be `parkeddomain.com/folder` or `parkeddomain.com/folder/folder/file.php`

- and not `parkeddomain.com/_domains/myparkeddomain_com/folder` or `parkeddomain.com/_domains/myparkeddomain_com/folder/folder/file.php`
- ...Makes sense?

So essentially what I want is my website on my `parkeddomain.com` to load from my `public_html/_domains/myparkeddomain_com/` as if it were loading from `public_html/`.

Is it possible to achieve this with `.htaccess` directive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what I was missing was an `.htaccess` in the the wordpress folder itself.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is best asked at the [Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) (I assumed your server is on Linux), since it is about Apache configuration.

From my experience, what you ask cannot be achieved from .htaccess, it requires a virtual host configuration entry. You can see examples at the [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html), or try Googling 'apache virtual host example'.